# MySQL query: returns only the user ids of users that participated in ALL events

Tags: mysql, sql

Table of which user participated in which event:

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | event |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 1     |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 2     |
+---------+-------+
| 2       | 1     |
+---------+-------+
```

I am looking for a query that returns only the user ids of users that participated in ALL events. So the query for the example table above should return only the user id 1, because user 2 missed event 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause.  If you don't have a separate table of events, you can use all events in this table:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct event) from t);
```

This assumes that users don't participate in the same event more than once, which seems like a reasonable assumption.